# JavacriptでFloatを、X時間XX分以下のような形式に変換したいです。

Tags: javascript

JavacriptでFloatを、X時間XX分以下のような形式に変換したいです。
1.2 => "1時間12分"
1.211 => "1時間12分"
1.11 => "1時間06分"
1.8 => "1時間48分"
1.89 => "1時間53分"

そのようなライブラリは存在しますか？
あるいは自分で実装する必要がありますか？

Comment: 単純な算数の問題に見えますが？

Comment: それはわかるんですが、ライブラリあったらそっち使いたいんですよね

Answer (score 1):

変数 `f` にそういう値が入っているとして、

```js
`${Math.floor(f)}時間${(Math.floor(f * 60) % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}分`
```

でいいんじゃないでしょうか。